# Serializing a List of Objects in Java to json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Currently i am trying to serialize a list of objects to array using Jackson . The Scenario here is if the list contains only one element , the list should be serialised as an object but not like an array . Is there any provision to do that?

I Created a Java Model and i am serialising to JSON using the below Code

```
A testObject = new A();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();           
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(testObject);
            System.out.append (json)
```

DataModel

```
class A{
private B b;
}

Class B{
private ArrayList<C> c;
}

Class c
{
private int i;
private String test;
}
```

Comment: You can check list size before converting to object.. if only 1 object is there get that object from list and convert that to json else convert list to json.. By default Jackson will convert list to json array only not as an object..

Comment: i  am trying to serialise a data model which has many such instances . So Is there any generic solution

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and outputs if possible.. and I'm not the one who has downvoted this.

Comment: I guess you could do that with reflection

Comment: @Lino Can you provide few more information

Comment: @User965207 could *you* please provide more information? Currently it is difficult for me to understand *what* you actually want to serialize. Is it an instance of class `A` which should then somehow find out that class `B` has a `List` which only would contain one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a SerializationFeature `WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED` by which we can obtain the above mentioned scenario in JSON

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(testObject) && testObject.size()==1? testObject.get(0):testObject);
```

Comment: Just read the comment:" i am trying to serialise a data model which has many such instances . So Is there any generic solution – User965207 3 mins ago". so i guess the answer i gave is not what exaclty is being asked.

Comment: Yes . Looking for a Generic Solution